# JSON to SQL - Extracting from JSON Array?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, extract

I have an exercise to extract some data from a larger JSON object however the data is added as multiple objects or perhaps an array of sorts.

An example below;

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"N.data.-ce731645-e4ef-4784-bc02-bb90b4c9e9e6": "Some Data",
"N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f": [
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
}'
```

I need to extract these datetime entries from the "date_1" identifier into ideally a CSV list.  From that I can do my own manipulations.

```
2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z, 2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z
```

I am familiar with JSON_VALUE() however not with its use outside of a simple piece of one dimensional  data.

What I have so far;

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"N.data.-ce731645-e4ef-4784-bc02-bb90b4c9e9e6": "Some Data",
"N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f": [
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
}'

SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

Is there a way to achive the expected output outside of complex substring() and replace() uses?

Using SQL Server 2017

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2017, the extraction can be done via native `OPENJSON`:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f": [
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
}'


SELECT  
    JSON_VALUE(child_value.value, '$.date_1') AS [key]    
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$') AS nda
cross apply openjson(nda.value, '$') as child_value
```

Results to:

```
key
2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z
2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z
```

> Is there a way to adjust this to extract the values for a specific
>   key, "N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f" in the
>   example

In this case, that query can be slightly simplified to:

```
DECLARE @id nvarchar(200) = 'N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f'

SELECT  
    JSON_VALUE(nda.value, '$.date_1') AS [key]    
FROM OPENJSON(@json, concat('$."',@id,'"')) AS nda
```

or without parametrization:

```
SELECT  
    JSON_VALUE(nda.value, '$.date_1') AS [key]    
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$."N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f"') AS nda
```

Comment: Thanks for this, its exactly the code to solve the issue.  The problem is I didnt include a real world example of the JSON.  I have edited my Question.  The JSON will contain multiple keys.  Is there a way to adjust this to extract the values for a specific key, "N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f" in the example.

Comment: @Bert682, I have updated the answer, this new requirement will make it also slightly faster to execute

Comment: Thanks, perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a cross apply with OPENJSON() using a with_clause:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f": [
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
}';

SELECT [b].*
FROM   OPENJSON(@json) [a]
CROSS APPLY
       OPENJSON([a].[Value])
           WITH (
                    [date_1] DATETIME '$.date_1'
                ) [b];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I've tried that as well, and then just got an empty result.  Anyway seems like you and me came up with the same solution, and since you've posted yours first, I've deleted mine and upvoted yours.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach, using `OPENJSON()`. With this approach you can get `key/value` pairs from your nested JSON array, even if this array has different key names.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = 
N'{"N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f": [
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date_2": "2019-10-21T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
}'

SELECT 
   x.[key] AS SessionData, 
   z.[key],
   z.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(x.[value])) y
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(y.[value])) z
--WHERE z.[key] = 'date_1'
```

Output:

```
SessionData                                                 key     value
N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f    date_1  2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z
N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f    date_1  2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z
N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f    date_2  2019-10-21T23:00:00.000Z
```

Update:
If you want to filter by key name, next may help:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"N.data.-ce731645-e4ef-4784-bc02-bb90b4c9e9e6": "Some Data",
"N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f": [
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date_1": "2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
}'

SELECT z.[value]
--SELECT STRING_AGG(z.[value], ', ') [Data] -- with string aggregation
FROM OPENJSON(@json) x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(x.[value])) y
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(y.[value])) z
WHERE x.[key] = 'N.data.sessionDates-7f1790d3-9175-43aa-962b-161ee3b8615f'
```

Output:

```
value
2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z
2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z
-- With string aggregation
--Data
--2018-10-20T23:00:00.000Z, 2018-10-21T23:00:00.000Z
```