# JSON Array in SQL - Extracting multiple values from JSON array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I have a JSON column [gca] that looks like this

```
[{
    "i":"https://some.image.URL 1",
    "u":"https://some.product.url",
    "n":"Product 1 Name",
    "q":"1",
    "sk":"sku number 1",
    "st":"$499.99"
 },
 {
    "i":"https://some.image.URL 2",
    "u":"https://some.product.url",
    "n":"Product 2 Name",
    "q":"1",
    "sk":"sku number 2",
    "st":"$499.99"
}]
```

I want to extract values specific to position. For example:

```
JSON_VALUE ([gca], '$[0].i') + ', ' + JSON_VALUE ([gca], '$[1].i')
```

So the result would be a string

```
image url 1, image url 2
```

I tried the cross apply solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006341/json-to-sql-extracting-from-json-array), but I get this error:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'h' is found at position 0

Expected results
-- https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaRjQ.png

Comment: which dbms (mysql, postgresql, tsql / sql-server, oracle) and version you are using?

Comment: See the answer here. It looks like you need to wrap your JSON in {}

Comment: Since the question references sql, i assume you are querying this data from some form of database. Can you share your query string? and also mention your dbms in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is correct and based on the `JSON` data in the question, the reason for this *"... JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'h' is found at position 0' error ... "* error is somewhere else.

Your `JSON` text is a valid `JSON` array, so you have two possible approaches to get your expected results:

- if this `JSON` array has always two items, you should use `JSON_VALUE()` to access each item
- if the count of the items is not known, you should use `OPENJSON()` with additional `CROSS APPLY` operator and string aggregation function.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [gca] nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   ([gca])
VALUES
   (N'[{"i":"https://some.image.URL 1","u":"https://some.product.url","n":"Product 1 Name","q":"1","sk":"sku number 1","st":"$499.99"},{"i":"https://some.image.URL 2","u":"https://some.product.url","n":"Product 2 Name","q":"1","sk":"sku number 2","st":"$499.99"}]'),
   (N'[{"i":"https://some.image.URL 1","u":"https://some.product.url","n":"Product 1 Name","q":"1","sk":"sku number 1","st":"$499.99"},{"i":"https://some.image.URL 2","u":"https://some.product.url","n":"Product 2 Name","q":"1","sk":"sku number 2","st":"$499.99"}]')
```

Statements:

```
-- For fixed structure with two items
SELECT JSON_VALUE ([gca], '$[0].i') + ', ' + JSON_VALUE ([gca], '$[1].i') AS [http]
FROM #Data

-- For JSON array with multiple items and SQL Server 2017+ 
SELECT j.*
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT STRING_AGG([http], ',') AS [http]
   FROM OPENJSON(d.[gca]) WITH ([http] varchar(max) '$.i') 
) j

-- For JSON array with multiple items
SELECT STUFF(j.[http], 1, 1, N'') AS [http]
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CONCAT(',', [http])
   FROM OPENJSON(d.[gca]) WITH ([http] varchar(max) '$.i')
   FOR XML PATH('')
) j([http])
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------
http
-------------------------------------------------
https://some.image.URL 1,https://some.image.URL 2
https://some.image.URL 1,https://some.image.URL 2
```

Note, that `JSON` support was intoduced in SQL Server 2016 and `STRING_AGG()` was introduced in SQL Server 2017. For string aggregation in earlier versions use `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: Hi @Zhorov,

Thanks for the response. Count of items is unknown, that's why I am avoiding doing a manual string 1 +','+ string 2
I used this as a subquery with other columns from the same table
SELECT Column 1,
              Column 2,
(
    SELECT  
       JSON_VALUE(child_value.value, '$.date_1') AS [key]    
       FROM OPENJSON([gca], '$') AS nda
       cross apply openjson(nda.value, '$') as child_value
    )
FROM #Temp3

Comment: and now I get
'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'
Along with
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'h' is found at position 0.

Comment: @oneThousand3   If I understand your statement in the comment correctly, you don't need `CROSS APPLY` (`... Unexpected character 'h' is found at position 0 ... ` error ), but you need to aggregate strings (`... Subquery returned more than 1  ...` error ). Probably this will help: `SELECT Column1, (SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_VALUE([value], '$.i'), ',') AS [key] FROM OPENJSON([gca], '$')) FROM #Temp3`

Comment: Hi, Forgot to mention, String_Agg is not supported as I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: @oneThousand3 For SQL Server 2016 use `FOR XML PATH` for string aggregation, see updaated answer.

Comment: Hi Zhorov, that did not do it for me. In your #Data, values are already separated. For example Value 1 is "i'... Value 2 is "i'...

Comment: Here's my table
CREATE TABLE #JSONData
(
[gca] NVARCHAR(MAX)
,[User] INT
);
INSERT INTO #JSONData
VALUES ('
{"basketitems":[{"i":"https://www.image1.com",
                 "url":"https://www.url-1.html",
     "name":"Product 1",
     "quantity":"1",
     "sku":"112233",
     "subtotal":"$24.99"},

     {"i":"https://www.image2.com",
     "url":"https://www.url-2.html",
     "name":"Product 2",
     "quantity":"1",
     "sku":"112244",
     "subtotal":"$24.99"}]}

Comment: and I am looking for results -

Comment: Image                    | Product    | Quantity |  subtotal |  User
-------                  |  -----     | ------   | ----------| --------
https://www.image1.com   | Product 1  |  1       |  24.99    |  1
https://www.image2.com   | Product 2  |  1       |  24.99    |  1

Comment: @oneThousand3 Can you post your expected results in the question. The links in the comments are not valid. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks here's the expected results. Also edited in question
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaRjQ.png