# How to parse the JSON arrays with OPENJSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have JSON data type in one of the columns in table as:

```json
{
  "phones":["+16024000022"]
}
```

I tried to use next in order to parse this column to be readable:

```sql
SELECT phones, m.phone_numbers 
  FROM [AuthX].dbo.migration m
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( m.phone_numbers)
  WITH (
        phones NVARCHAR(50) '$'
       )
```

But I am getting null values in new column phones.

Comment: @jarlh I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Replacing `'$'` with `'$.phones[0]'` will do what you need if extracting only one component is enough

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thank you so much!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan what about if I have like this {"phones":["+14809074223","+16024000022"]} ?

Comment: `phone1 NVARCHAR(50) '$.phones[0]', phone2 NVARCHAR(50) '$.phones[1]'` to be a static solution, bu t I don't know if there's a dynamic one :) Btw, perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57964561/5841306) might help in order to get the logic.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thank you so much, it works just great.

Comment: you're welcome DKCroat, good luck! Btw, Serg's answer is pretty good I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a JSON array members in a form of key - value pairs. For example

```
SELECT  id, [key], value
FROM 
  (values (1, '{"phones":["+14809074223","+16024000022"]}')
) m (id,phone_numbers )
CROSS apply OPENJSON(m.phone_numbers, '$.phones');
```

Comment: @DKCroat In this case `[key]` represents the array index